# calling server function from client side

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, webmethod

I need to call a method in the code behind from client side using json, but the method never got called, and the error "c" is blank.  What did I do wrong here?

Client side code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "MyPage.aspx/CheckItem",
    data: {item: item},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        if (result) {
            errorMessage.innerHTML = 'WARNING: Item exists.';
            return false;
        }
    },
    error: function (a,b,c) {
        alert("error: " + c);
    }
});
```

Server side code:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static bool CheckItem(string item)
{
    DataContext dc = new DataContext();

    var record = dc.MyTable.Where(x => x.Item == item).FirstOrDefault();
    if (record != null)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you make the request to `MyPage.aspx/CheckItem`, instead of `MyPage.aspx/MyMethod`?

Comment: yes, I did that (it was a typo)

Comment: where is that code in your page? Are you sure the ajax code is even being called at all?

Comment: I put a break point, it went to "error" and the third parameter (which is "c") is blank

Comment: Try adding `cache: false` to the ajax request

Comment: The ajax code may be called, but the request may not be sent to the server. Can you confirm this? Use the browser's network inspector to monitor incoming and outcoming requests

Comment: did try that too, nothing happened

Comment: "MyPage.aspx/CheckItem" doesn't appear to be a proper URL. Can you navigate to it in a browser?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly enclose your parameter with quotes/double quotes. Please see below.

```
            var item = 0;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/WebForm1.aspx/CheckItem",
                data: '{"item":"' + item +'"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                error: function (errorThrown) {

                    alert(errorThrown.responseText + "what's wrong?" + " " + errorThrown);
                },
                success: function (msg) {

                    alert(msg.d);
                    return false;
                    // Do something interesting here.
                }
            });
```

> ```
>     [WebMethod]
>     public static bool CheckItem(string item)
>     {
>         return true;
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a method in an ASP page, you're going to need to add some logic inside the ASP page to call the function. You can't just call it directly from $.ajax(). For example, your ajax call might be:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "MyPage.aspx",
    data: {
        item: item,
        method: 'CheckItem'
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        if (result) {
            errorMessage.innerHTML = 'WARNING: Item exists.';
            return false;
        }
    },
    error: function (a,b,c) {
        alert("error: " + c);
    }
});
```

And then inside your asp code, you would look for the "method" form variable and call the specified method.